# Is it OK to add to a correct answer (from someone else) for your own question?

Tags: discussion, answers, etiquette

I sometimes think of additional answers to my question after I see a good answer. But if there is a good answer, I'd rather **add to the good answer** than post another answer. But I'm not sure if that might offend the poster, especially if it somehow "costs" them points.

Currently, I usually make these edits in comments, but since *I* am the "authority" on the answer (according to Stack Exchange's model :-)  then it seems better to put additional valid solutions in the actual answer.

Comment: "I often find more solutions to a problem after I post it." Sounds to me like you need to do some searching a bit more first...

Comment: Could be. In the particular cases this has happened, it's been on the UX Stackexchange. I'll see an answer and then based on that answer have another idea. In those cases I dont mean I literatlly "found" and answer somewhere, I mean that I "thought" another solution.  Many times that's just an iterative process: you ask, you see an answer, that sparks another idea.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You should not be adding additional content to another answer, no.  Edits are for improving the content that is currently there, making it clearer, easier for the reader to understand what the author is *already saying*, and not to put entirely new content into their mouth.

You could comment on the answer with the additional information if you wanted; the author may choose to incorporate it into their answer if they would like to (citing you as appropriate).

If the information that you want to add is more than can fit into a comment, then it may indeed be appropriate to post an additional answer (just be sure that it *answers the question* and doesn't just provide tangential information).  If the additional information is valuable, it may be upvoted.  It's also possible that the existing answer's author will see yours, and incorporate some if your information in their answer (again, citing as appropriate), also putting all of the information into a single answer.

Comment: could be me who misunderstood, but think Clay meant taking an answer from someone else's question which answers his, and posting that answer on his own question.

Comment: @James I don't read this question that way, but if that were the case, then the questions would be duplicates, and one should be closed as a duplicate of the other.

Comment: @Servy Although, just because the same answer answers multiple questions, [doesn't mean that the questions are duplicates](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/106781/225437).

Comment: @James Based on Clay Nichols's new comment, it sounds more like this is a question about "X's answer gave me a great idea that's even better than X's answer.  Should I update X's answer so that X can still get the credit?"  I still agree with Servy's answer that, "nope, you should create a new answer", but I think the intent is a bit clearer now.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor In principle, sure, in practice, not really.  If the questions are really different enough to not be duplicates, then they really shouldn't have the *exact* same answer.  One answer may reference another, quote portions of it, and then build on it to tailor it to another answer, if the questions aren't in fact duplicates.  Regardless, it's pretty clear that this meta question is about a single question, not multiple questions.

Comment: @Servy I upvoted your previous comment because I agree, it's not common in practice.  However, I just came across an instance on math.SE, where [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/46777/72995) would also have been suitable as an answer to [a question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/467640/72995) I asked about two years later. The first question, however, is sort of a list question and community wiki, which suggests a possible heuristic:  if some answer is suitable for multiple questions, then it's more likely that at least one of those question is has issues.